# Система для ревью кода.

Tags: контроль-версий

Нужна фришная система для ревью кода. Есть сервер на меркуриал. И есть два варианта или система для ревью именно для меркурила. Либо переходить на git(только нужен закрытый git репозиторий(насколько я понимаю локальный, так как внешний платный)) + "система для ревью". Подскажите что оптимально и как это можно реализовать, и чтобы бесплатно фришное.

Comment: Вариант внешний закрытый репозиторий меркуриал на bitbucket рассматривали? До 5 пользователей бесплатно (см. [bitbucket pricing](https://bitbucket.org/product/pricing?tab=host-in-the-cloud))

Comment: @insolor на 5 не подойдет к сожалению.